# Android throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, nullpointerexception, amazon-dynamodb

I am stuck. I got error `NullPointerException` on buttonClick. I could not identify where is the null.Below are my codes for your references. I have stucked with this error for 2 weeks now. :(

```
public class DynamoDB extends Activity{
private String tableName = "Tesis_FTSM";
private AmazonDynamoDBClient client;

public void DynamoDB() throws IOException
{
    AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(DynamoDB.class.getResourceAsStream("Credentials.properties"));
    client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
    client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
}

public void putItem(String Title, String Author, String Year, String Supervisor, String Program)
{
    Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<>();

    item.put("Id", new AttributeValue().withN("1"));
    item.put("Title", new AttributeValue().withS(Title));
    item.put("Author", new AttributeValue().withS(Author));
    item.put("Year", new AttributeValue().withS(Year));
    item.put("Supervisor", new AttributeValue().withS(Supervisor));
    item.put("Program", new AttributeValue().withS(Program));

    PutItemRequest itemRequest = new PutItemRequest().withTableName(
            tableName).withItem(item);
    client.putItem(itemRequest);
    item.clear();
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    final EditText title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_View);
    final EditText author = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.author_View);
    final EditText year = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.year_View);
    final EditText supervisor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.super_View);
    final Spinner prog = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.prog_Spinner);

    final String tajuk = title.getText().toString();
    final String au = author.getText().toString();
    final String tahun = year.getText().toString();
    final String selia = supervisor.getText().toString();
    final String program = prog.getSelectedItem().toString();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload_Btn);

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save to Table", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Task obj = new Task();
                    obj.execute();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        });


    }

    public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            Looper.prepare();

            try {

                DynamoDB db = new DynamoDB();

                db.putItem(tajuk,au,tahun,selia,program);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Looper.loop();
            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String page) {
            // onPostExecute
        }
    }


}
```

LOGCAT ERROR

```
06-24 12:53:25.321  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.DynamoDB.putItem(DynamoDB.java:61)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:66)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:44)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-24 12:53:25.331  23051-23079/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: What you have at line 61 in DynamoDB.java

Comment: Provide your DynamoDB class

Comment: prblem in your Database code

Comment: I suggest you use List<> instead of Map

Comment: Please provide an MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move these codes after your `setContentView` in the `onCreate` method.

```
final EditText title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_View);
final EditText author = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.author_View);
final EditText year = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.year_View);
final EditText supervisor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.super_View);
final Spinner prog = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.prog_Spinner);

final String tajuk = title.getText().toString();
final String au = author.getText().toString();
final String tahun = year.getText().toString();
final String selia = supervisor.getText().toString();
final String program = prog.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: also dont keep the variables local. Create them in your activity and then find them in oncreate.